# Deployment Desctiptor - rules concerning to actual path name of servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Iam looking at DD and I cant see anything which indicates the actual path name of servlet. How the container uses the class name to find   a specific servlet class file?

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name> Name</servlet-name>
<servlet-class> test.Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet> 


<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name> Name</servlet-name>
<url-pattern> /Public</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What rules does the Deployment Desctiptor use?

thanks indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD follows below steps ::

1. Matches URl pattern.
2. For matched pattern, find servlet name.
3. for that name find servlet class